# How to fetch field data from firestore while the list will increase, Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

[image: This is what the data in cloud firestore looks like]

I have my data saved, this is from a checkbox list so I get is the fieldname and the checkbox result, a boolean data. I wish to print all the true data in a ListView and at the same time the data for the field will increase. For example, now we have asthma, atrial and copd but in future there might be an increase in field like stroke added to the checkbox. Is there a way to fetch all true data will the database might increase?

Comment: Are you asking how to [listen and respond to updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to your database?

Comment: Please, provide more information.